# Programmatically Set Table Name in the FROM Clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, linked-server

Is there a way to programmatically set the table names used in the FROM clause?

The reason is we have a different table names in our prod vs. dev environment therefore we need to set the table names accordingly to be used in our reports, based on the different environments.

For example:

In prod the database name is 123prd, in dev it would be 123dev

In prod the database name is 456prd, in dev it would be 456dev

The report runs against database 123prd and we need to INNER JOIN to another table in the 456prd database.

So for the Prod environment it would be something like below:

```
USE 123prd
SELECT * 
FROM aTable a 
JOIN 456prd.dbo.bTable b 
ON a.id = b.id
```

However since the report needs to work correctly according to the different environment Prod vs. Dev I will need to programatically change the database name in the FROM clause.

So this is what I have:

```
DECLARE @456DBName VARCHAR(16)
SET @456DBName = REPLACE(DB_NAME(), '123', '456')

USE 123prd
SELECT * 
FROM aTable a 
JOIN CONCAT(@456DbName, '.dbo.bTable') b 
ON a.id = b.id
```

I got error invalid syntax when using CONCAT or +
Is there a correct way on how to do linked server programmatically? Sorry about bad English by the way, hopefully my question makes sense.

Comment: You need Dynamic SQL for dynamic table names.

Comment: Do you need this to use in something other than ssms?

Comment: Thanks I'll use Dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You have limited options, because you cannot just set the project that way.

One option is to do away with three part naming.  Just reference tables *within* the database.  This works if production/development only consist of one database.

Another option is to wrap all references with views (these could also incorporate business logic).  This is particularly helpful if "production" and "development" can span multiple databases.  The views can be in one place -- but they probably need to be created using deployment scripts that use dynamic SQL.

A related option would use synonyms.  I have not personally used these for this purpose, but they should work.

And finally, there is dynamic SQL.  One method is to store the queries and have a stored procedure do the replacement.  Heck, you could even store the queries as views for a specific database -- and have a stored procedure do the substitution for other environments.

Comment: Re: synonyms - I can confirm that they will work. I've used them for this exact scenario, so that code didn't have to be changed as it was promoted from development to test to production.

Comment: Got it, Dynamics SQL it is then. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can query across multiple servers using 'server groups' in ssms.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/register-servers/execute-statements-against-multiple-servers-simultaneously?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I think I will go with Dynamics SQL as recommended by other users.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1. You can do it with code, using different methods depending on the environment variable and calling different store procedures or same name different schema.

Option 2. You can use Dynamic Queries. You could create a table to manage the configuration to what schema/table to use depending on the parameter you send from your server. Then just execute the dynamic query.

Ie.

```
DECLARE @Prefix VARCHAR(10) = 'dev';

DECLARE @Params NVARCHAR(200) = '@Prefix VARCHAR(10)'
     , @Query  NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT [Id] FROM [Schema].['+@Prefix+'TableName]';

EXECUTE [sp_executesql]
 @Query ,
 @Params ,
 @Prefix = @Prefix
```

Comment: Got it, I think I will go with Dynamic Queries. Thanks.